# use search result in replace statement with vim substitute

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I've got a file with a whole heap of words of the form 'foo' and i want to change them to Literal('foo'). The following :s command `:%s/'.*'/Literal('.*')/gci` finds the things i want to change but then it replaces them all with Literal('.*') rather than Literal('foo')

```
Examples:
I get:
'_' -> Literal('.*') 
'dog' -> Literal('.*') 
I want: 
'_' -> Literal('_') 
'dog' -> Literal('dog')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it

```
:%s/\('.*'\)/Literal(\1)/gci
```

You need to save the match and reference it in the replace.  You were inserting a literal (no pun) .* in the replace.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to casey's answer with explicit capturing is to restrict the match with `\zs` (start) and `\ze` (end), to assert that the single quotes are there, but don't include them. Then, you can just refer to the match in the replacement part with `&`:

```
:%s/'\zs.*\ze'/Literal(&)/gci
```